# post() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I want to test my FastAPI Routes but I get this error:

```
TypeError: post() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I used this method:

```py
def test_create_user(client):
    data = {"username":"testuser","email":"testuser@nofoobar.com","password":"testing"}
    response = client.post("/users/",json.dumps(data))
    assert response.status_code == 200 
    assert response.json()["email"] == "testuser@nofoobar.com"
    assert response.json()["is_active"] == True
```

Comment: What is `client`? And is this the actual code causing the TypeError? It doesn't seem to be.

Comment: You need to post the full stack trace and not just the error itself, so we can have an idea as to the context of the error. You're clearly only passing 2 args in the code you've shown so there's just no way to help, that I can see unless you give us more info.

Answer (score 2):

Specify how you are sending data, for your case it is body as `json`:

```
response = client.post("/users/",json = data)
```

No need to convert `data` to `json`, it will be automatically done

Answer (score 1):

You can use these:

```
response = client.post("/users/", params=data)
```

or

```
response = client.post("/users/", headers=data)
```

or

```
response = client.post("/users/", data=data)
```